# Get a list of all objects with the same key inside a jsonb array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `mytable` and a JSONB column `employees` that contains data like this:

```
[      {
         "name":"Raj",
         "email":"raj@gmail.com",
         "age":32
          
},
      {
         "name":"Mohan",
         "email":"Mohan@yahoo.com",
         "age":21
          
        }   
]
```

I would like to extract only the names and save them in a list format, so the resulting cell would look like this:

```
['Raj','Mohan']
```

I have tried

```
select l1.obj ->> 'name' names
from mytable t
cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.employees)   as l1(obj)
```

but this only returns the name of the first array element.
How do I get the name of all array elements?
Thanks!

`PostgreSQL 11.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres 12, you can use `jsonb_path_query_array()`:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(employees, '$[*].name') as names
from mytable
```

In earlier versions you need to unnest then aggregate back:

```
select (select jsonb_agg(e -> 'name') 
        from jsonb_array_elements(employees) as t(e)) as names
from mytable
```